# nvd3 mulitbarchart - with useinteractiveguideline

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

Looks like useInteractiveGuideline is not available on the multibarchart. Is there any way to create a tooltip that is similar to this? I tried defining a custom tooltipContent but it doesn't look like all the info for the group is available (only for the stream). Ideally, it would be a tooltip similar to the stackedArea interactiveGuideline.

Comment: Can you show some code you tried, so we can point out where things might be wrong.

Comment: I think I am just going to use c3js instead. It has more of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It was already added but not released yet.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/1368